# HP Webcam HD 2300 always using 48% of USB bandwith, why?

Tags: usb, webcam

Used bandwidth seems to be independent of resolution and frame format (tested with GraphEdt.exe).

Measured via Windows 7 device manager, advanced properties of the Enhanced Host Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is unintuitive, but that dialog shows the bandwidth allocation and not the bandwidth currently used for most devices.